# Can i use IF statement in this query?

Tags: sql

Hi I am wondering if i can use IF statement in the following query..

```
select * from Table
Where Field1 = 'john' and
if Field2 = 'Mike'
Then(dbo.StateId(gp.SiD) Like '%' + @StateName +'%'))
Else Nothing**
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can use IF statments in sql queries, but the syntax of the query may depend on the database (mysql, oracle, ...).

Comment: @ssoler - It is SQL server I think (from `dbo.`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

```
SELECT *
FROM   Table
WHERE  Field1 = 'john'
       AND ( Field2 <> 'Mike'
              OR dbo.StateId(gp.SiD) LIKE '%' + @StateName + '%' )
```

(Your sample code doesn't make clear to me what should happen if `Field2` is `NULL`)

Comment: The correct answer is `yes`.  Though as you point out it is not necessary.

Comment: @mellamokb - Not in SQL Server it isn't. `IF` is a flow of control construct and can't be used in a query.

Comment: I think @ssoler's comment was more helpful... yes technically, you can't use the exact syntax `IF`, but you can use that concept in SQL queries.

Comment: @mellamokb  - In SQL Server only by doing something like `AND 1= CASE WHEN cond THEN 1 END` which makes the `WHERE` clause unsargable.

Answer (score 0):

I think **[SELECT/CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)** will work for what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
   from Table
   Where Field1 = 'john' 
     and case when Field2 = 'Mike' 
            Then (dbo.StateId(gp.SiD) Like '%' + @StateName +'%')) 
            Else ( true or false based on inclusion ) end
```